# extracting contents of Datatable into list C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am experimenting to take datatable contents into a list. I am using following code but its not working correctly.

```
public List<object> ShowMessage()
    {
        List<object> obj = new List<object>();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");

        dt.Rows.Add("1","AAA");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "BBB");
        dt.Rows.Add("3", "CCC");

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {

            obj.Add(dr);
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

I am new and not sure I am doing in a right way or I need to use some thing else. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What you are expecting to have in that list? Should it be list of strings "AAA", "BBB", "CCC" or something else?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy yes, I am expecting a list of strings with "AAA", "BBB" and "CCC".

Comment: Side note - `ShowMessage` is not the best name for method which returns list of some data and doesn't show anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting your DataTable to list of name strings (with help of [Linq to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
List<string> names = 
    dt.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<string>("Name")).ToList();
```

Which is same as

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();

foreach(DataRow r in dt.Rows)    
    names.Add((string)r["Name"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a too abstract example. This one use a possible class named Person

```
public class Person
{
   public int PersonID;
   public string Name;
   // other fields will follow in future
}

public List<Person> GetPersonList()
{
   List<Person> people = new List<Person>();

   // This is just as example, because in real code 
   // you get this table from a database
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("ID");
   dt.Columns.Add("Name");

   dt.Rows.Add(1,"John");
   dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mark");
   dt.Rows.Add(3, "Steve");

   // Loop over the rows and construct a Person instance for every row
   // Add that row to the List<Person> to return 
   foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
   {
       Person p = new Person() {PersonID =Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]), Name = dr[1].ToString());
       people.Add(p);
   }
   return people;
}
```

By the way, this pattern of code, is exactly what a good ORM do for you. A little research for Entity Framework or Dapper would be very useful

Answer (score 0):

@Karni: you were close to what you need. however below is the modified version of your code example so that you achieve what you need..

```
public class Obj
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ListObj : List<Obj>
{

}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");

        dt.Rows.Add("1", "AAA");
        dt.Rows.Add("2", "BBB");
        dt.Rows.Add("3", "CCC");

        ListObj objListObj = new ListObj();

        //to fill the list / collection
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            objListObj.Add(new Obj() { ID = Convert.ToInt16(dt.Rows[i][0]), Name = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() });
        }


        //To verify if the collection is filled.
        foreach (var item in objListObj)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.ID + " : " + item.Name);
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```